Why does gazebo11 load the controller model and fall into the ground?
When I loaded the model into gazebo, after I clicked the pause button, the model fell into the ground, became a mess, and seemed to overlap left and right, as shown in the figure below. And when I changed the damping friction, the robot was difficult to control and seemed to be very unsmooth.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I have checked that the urdf file is correct and the controller is correct. I just changed the parameter  and the robot became like this. This problem has been bothering me for a long time.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-4-g7f85cfe  Build Version: 1.6.7995.38578
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot name="yuquan"
  xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:include filename="$(find robot_description_v2)/urdf/transmission.xacro"/>
  <xacro:include filename="$(find robot_description_v2)/urdf/gazebo.xacro"/>


<xacro:property name="damping_value" value="3.10" />
<xacro:property name="friction_value" value="1.10" />

  <xacro:if value="$(arg DEBUG_YUQUAN)">
    <link name="world"/>
    <joint name="base_static_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="world"/>
      <child link="base_link"/>
    </joint>
  </xacro:if>



  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.031702 9.0654E-05 -0.2408"       rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="5.245" />
      <inertia                  
        ixx="0.071581"   ixy="-1.26E-06"  ixz="-0.000387674"  iyy="0.010663975" iyz="-1.67E-05"  izz="0.074910789" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"     rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/base_link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.64314 0.56078 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/base_link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

     <link
    name="L_hip_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.10126 1.8753E-05 -0.072211"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.5221" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0058115"
        ixy="-7.58E-06"
        ixz="0.0032614"
        iyy="0.010053"
        iyz="1.86E-05"
        izz="0.0076041" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_hip_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.28627 0.66275 0.32941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"

        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_hip_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
    <joint
    name="L_hip_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0.105 -0.17"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="L_hip_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link

    name="L_hip2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.079457 0.0068232 0.00011456"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.3619" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0034092"
        ixy="0.00015612"
        ixz="-2.33E-05"
        iyy="0.0043191"
        iyz="1.61E-05"
        izz="0.0042029" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_hip2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 0 0.50196 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_hip2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="L_hip2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.091 0 -0.09"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="L_hip_Link" />
    <child
      link="L_hip2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit

      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="L_thigh_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0036773 0.0023572 -0.14985"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="3.5738" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.039141"
        ixy="-8.43E-05"
        ixz="-0.0021682"
        iyy="0.039089"
        iyz="-0.00092606"
        izz="0.0083235" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_thigh_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.89804 0.91765 0.92941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_thigh_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  
  <joint
    name="L_thigh_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.091 0 0"
      rpy="0 -0.3236 0" />
    <parent
      link="L_hip2_Link" />
    <child
      link="L_thigh_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="L_calf_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0070583 -0.0010487 -0.13945"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6351" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.022592"
        ixy="-3.27E-05"
        ixz="0.00012856"
        iyy="0.022319"
        iyz="0.00030619"
        izz="0.0028682" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_calf_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.89804 0.91765 0.92941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_calf_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="L_calf_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 -0.4"

      rpy="0 0.6472 0" />
    <parent
      link="L_thigh_Link" />
    <child
      link="L_calf_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="L_toe_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="1.2891E-16 8.7014E-15 -0.013338"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.87997" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00015285"
        ixy="0"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="0.00015388"
        iyz="0"
        izz="3.6221E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_toe_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_toe_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="L_toe_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 -0.4"
      rpy="0 -0.3036 0" />
    <parent
      link="L_calf_Link" />
    <child

      link="L_toe_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="L_toe2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.031026 -5.4418E-05 -0.051428"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.97299" />
      <inertia
         ixx="0.0010393"
        ixy="1.93E-06"
        ixz="-0.00046374"
        iyy="0.0053103"
        iyz="-8.1E-07"
        izz="0.0053431" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_toe2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.89804 0.91765 0.92941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/L_toe2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint

    name="L_toe2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 -0.024"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="L_toe_Link" />
    <child
      link="L_toe2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="700"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="R_hip_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
         xyz="-0.10125 -0.0003997 -0.072603"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.5221" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0058459"
        ixy="6.32E-05"
        ixz="0.0033184"
        iyy="0.010043"
        iyz="-6E-07"
        izz="0.0076471" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_hip_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.28627 0.66275 0.32941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_hip_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="R_hip_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 -0.105 -0.17"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="R_hip_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="R_hip2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.079836 -0.0068232 0.00042847"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.3619" />
      <inertia
       ixx="0.0034414"
        ixy="-0.00019202"
        ixz="-8.93E-06"
        iyy="0.004339"
        iyz="-4.59E-05"
        izz="0.0041907" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_hip2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.28627 0.66275 0.32941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_hip2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="R_hip2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.091 0 -0.09"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="R_hip_Link" />
    <child
      link="R_hip2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="R_thigh_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0055385 -0.003604 -0.14928"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="3.5738" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.039243"
        ixy="7.76E-05"
        ixz="-0.0024373"
        iyy="0.039257"
        iyz="0.0010148"
        izz="0.0083113" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_thigh_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_thigh_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="R_thigh_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.091 0 0"
      rpy="0 -0.3236 0" />
    <parent
      link="R_hip2_Link" />
    <child
      link="R_thigh_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="R_calf_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0081421 0.001051 -0.13939"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="2.6351" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.022572"
        ixy="2.7E-05"
        ixz="-7.4E-05"
        iyy="0.022337"
        iyz="-0.00030447"
        izz="0.0029066" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_calf_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.89804 0.91765 0.92941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_calf_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="R_calf_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 -0.4"
      rpy="0 0.6472 0" />
    <parent
      link="R_thigh_Link" />
    <child
      link="R_calf_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="0.7"
      friction="0.3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="R_toe_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-3.7779E-15 1.9984E-15 -0.013338"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.87997" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00015285"
        ixy="0"
        ixz="0"
        iyy="0.00015388"
        iyz="0"
        izz="3.6221E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_toe_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_toe_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="R_toe_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 -0.4"
      rpy="0 -0.3036 0" />
    <parent
      link="R_calf_Link" />
    <child
      link="R_toe_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
      <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="500"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="7"
      friction="3" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="R_toe2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.031026 -5.4416E-05 -0.051428"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.97299" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.0010393"
        ixy="1.93E-06"
        ixz="-0.00046374"
        iyy="0.0053103"
        iyz="-8.1E-07"
        izz="0.0053431" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_toe2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.89804 0.91765 0.92941 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_description_v2/dae/R_toe2_Link.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="R_toe2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0 -0.024"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="R_toe_Link" />
    <child
      link="R_toe2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="3.14"
      effort="700"
      velocity="500" />
    <dynamics
      damping="7"
      friction="3" />
  </joint>
</robot>


